# XSL: issue with position() in xsl:if

Tags: xml, xslt, position

My task is i have to display all the node labels, before displaying i need to check whether those node/label is there in the /Datum/DCR/Global/* if it is there then i want to display the value from the global elements child or else i want to display from the node elements label in my example node/label "home" is not there in global elements child nodes so i will display from /Result/site-map/segment/node[1]/label and "Inventory" is there in the Global elements Child node so i need to display inventory from /Datum/DCR/Global/Inventory.

**XML file:-**

```
<Properties>
    <Data>
        <Datum ID="D01" Type="DCR" Name="Global">
            <DCR Category="BAT" Type="global">
                <Global>
                    <FindaDealer>Find a Dealer</FindaDealer> 
                    <Tools>Tools</Tools> 
                    <Inventory>Inventory</Inventory> 
                    <ContactDealers>Contact Dealers</ContactDealers> 
                 </Global>
            </DCR>
        </Datum>
        <Result>
            <site-map id="hnh1clwg" >
                <segment id="0" >
                    <node id="hnhi" >
                        <label key="">home</label> 
                    </node>
                    <node id="hn4h">
                      <label key="">Offers</label>
                    </node>
                    <node id="hn4l">
                      <label key="">Tools</label>
                    </node>
                    <node id="hn62">
                      <label key="">Inventory</label>
                    </node>
                  </segment>
              </site-map>
        </Result>
    </Data>
</properties>
```

**XSL code:-**

```
<xsl:element name="ul">
        <xsl:for-each select="Properties/Data/Result/site-map/segment/node">
            <li>
                <a href="#"> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Properties/Data/Datum[@Name='Global']/DCR/Global/*">
                        <xsl:with-param name="nodelabel" select="label"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>          
                </a>
            </li>                                   
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>          

<xsl:template name="Glossary" match="/Properties/Data/Datum[@Name='Global']/DCR/Global/*">
    <xsl:param name="nodelabel"/>
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="."/>

    <xsl:if test="($nodelabel = $value)">
        <xsl:text>From Global element : </xsl:text>                                             
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($nodelabel = $value) and position()=last()">
        <xsl:text>From Sitemap : </xsl:text>                                                
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

**Output i am getting:-**

```
From Sitemap : 
From Sitemap : 
From Global element : From Sitemap : 
From Global element : From Sitemap :
```

**desired output :-**

```
From Sitemap : 
From Sitemap : 
From Global element : 
From Global element :
```

any pointers would be helpfull.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand your logic in this fragment, there seems to be no need to apply templates to *all* the `Global/*` elements for every site-map node.  You could define a *key* on the global values to let you look up those nodes by value

```
<xsl:key name="globalValues" match="Global/*" use="." />
```

and now you can define two different templates for nodes, one that matches nodes that *do* have counterparts in the global list and another for nodes that *don't*:

```
<xsl:template match="node[key('globalValues', label)]" priority="10">
  <xsl:text>From Global element : </xsl:text>
  <!-- within this template you can use
         key('globalValues', label)
       to access the corresponding Global/* element -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node" priority="5">
  <xsl:text>From Sitemap : </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

(the explicit priorities aren't strictly necessary in this case as the default priorities will do the right thing, but I think they make the intention clearer).  Now with these in place you simply apply-templates to all the node elements and the template matcher will pick the appropriate one for each node:

```
<xsl:element name="ul">
    <xsl:for-each select="Properties/Data/Result/site-map/segment/node">
        <li>
            <a href="#"> 
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
            </a>
        </li>                                   
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

or more idiomatically, move the `<li>` and `<a>` into the target templates and get rid of the `for-each`, just

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Properties/Data/Result/site-map/segment/node" />
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much your logic is working i am new to xslt i didn't use xsl:key before i have one more question how to get the value of globalvalue key  if the nodes matches. can i use xsl:value-of?

Comment: i gave "<xsl:value-of select="key('globalvalues',label)" />" to get the matched value but it's not working.

Comment: @user2962780 like most things in XML the key name is case sensitive - if you have an `<xsl:key name="globalValues">` then you need to use `key('globalValues', label)`, not `key('globalvalues', label)`

Comment: Sorry i thought i gave same key name thank you it's working now.